# Identifying ACF field after a search result is matched in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, acfpro

Is it possible to get the ACF field name / ID where the search string matched? The ACF fields are also included with default search functionality of wordpress. So, when a search string is matched with an ACF field value, I also want to identify the field name/ID. Is that possible?

Comment: do you mean to searched text if matches with acf field then you want to get that acf field details right?

Comment: Yes, exactly :) Sorry for my bad explanation

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code script. I hope this will work for you.

```
$fields = get_fields(get_the_ID()); 
$acfField = array(); 
$search_query = get_search_query(); 
foreach( $fields as $name => $value ): 
if($search_query == $value){ 
$acfField['name'] = $name; 
$acfField['value'] = 
$value; break; 
} 
endforeach;
 print_r($acfField);
```

Put this it in loop of the `search.php` as :

```
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    $fields = get_fields(get_the_ID());
    $acfField = array();
    $search_query = get_search_query();
    foreach( $fields as $name => $value ):
    if($search_query == $value){
    $acfField['name'] = $name;
    $acfField['value'] = $value;
            break;
    }
    endforeach; 
     print_r($acfField);

    get_template_part( 'template-parts/post/content' ); 

  endwhile;
```

**Note:** Actually, we can not get all acf fields. We can only get all ACF fields of particular post by post ID using `get_fields(get_the_ID());`

Comment: Thanks for the quick help. I will soon try this and let you know.

Comment: Okay, you can use according to your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is add this lines to function.php

```
<?php

function list_searcheable_acf(){
  $list_searcheable_acf = array("title", "sub_title", "excerpt_short", "excerpt_long", "xyz", "myACF");
  return $list_searcheable_acf;
}

function advanced_custom_search( $where, &$wp_query ) {
    global $wpdb;

    if ( empty( $where ))
        return $where;

    // get search expression
    $terms = $wp_query->query_vars[ 's' ];

    // explode search expression to get search terms
    $exploded = explode( ' ', $terms );
    if( $exploded === FALSE || count( $exploded ) == 0 )
        $exploded = array( 0 => $terms );

    // reset search in order to rebuilt it as we whish
    $where = '';

    // get searcheable_acf, a list of advanced custom fields you want to search content in
    $list_searcheable_acf = list_searcheable_acf();
    foreach( $exploded as $tag ) :
        $where .= " 
          AND (
            (wp_posts.post_title LIKE '%$tag%')
            OR (wp_posts.post_content LIKE '%$tag%')
            OR EXISTS (
              SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta
                  WHERE post_id = wp_posts.ID
                    AND (";
        foreach ($list_searcheable_acf as $searcheable_acf) :
          if ($searcheable_acf == $list_searcheable_acf[0]):
            $where .= " (meta_key LIKE '%" . $searcheable_acf . "%' AND meta_value LIKE '%$tag%') ";
          else :
            $where .= " OR (meta_key LIKE '%" . $searcheable_acf . "%' AND meta_value LIKE '%$tag%') ";
          endif;
        endforeach;
            $where .= ")
            )
            OR EXISTS (
              SELECT * FROM wp_comments
              WHERE comment_post_ID = wp_posts.ID
                AND comment_content LIKE '%$tag%'
            )
            OR EXISTS (
              SELECT * FROM wp_terms
              INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy
                ON wp_term_taxonomy.term_id = wp_terms.term_id
              INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships
                ON wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id
              WHERE (
                taxonomy = 'post_tag'
                    OR taxonomy = 'category'                
                    OR taxonomy = 'myCustomTax'
                )
                AND object_id = wp_posts.ID
                AND wp_terms.name LIKE '%$tag%'
            )
        )";
    endforeach;
    return $where;
}
add_filter( 'posts_search', 'advanced_custom_search', 500, 2 );
```

Comment: my indentation gone wrong please copy the full code